# google apps script with UrlfetchApp.fetchAll() or with async/ await for multiple http requests?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I created some projects in Google Apps Script in the past for some automation, that also included some http-fetches. In the past, this worked with `.fetch()` pretty well, but now we need to fetch multiple urls.
Since apps script now uses V8 runtime I considered to do so with promises. I'm also quite new to async/await and promises in general.
So I considered to try the `UrlfetchApp.fetch()` within async functions, just to find out, that there's no difference in execution time.

I red, that `UrlfetchApp.fetch()` will always be sync, no matter whether you declare your function as async or not, due to the GAS-API-design. But I can't find detailed infos on this.
Is this true?

If yes: Then the only way to fetch multiple urls would be `UrlfetchApp.fetchAll()`, right?

If no: Means simple `.fetch()` would work inside async funcs (and could be chained in `Promise.all())` then I'd invest further time in this.

So, yes or no would help a lot here!

Comment: True>yes and yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, Urlfetchapp runs synchronously and although the syntax of promises are supported, it works synchronously too.

> Then the only way to fetch multiple urls would be UrlfetchApp.fetchAll(), right?

Yes

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/google-apps-script-community/629e694a-5dba-424f-992c-592e0d0f8874%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) community post by Steve Webster may help.

Comment: *"Promises do work, in that if you create one, and return it from your script, the script will wait until the promise resolves before it returns. However since there is no way to create any promise other than one that is immediately resolved, this doesn't really help you.

The first place we will probably add a promise, would be a new method to UrlFetchApp that returned a promise. But we don't plan to add any new V8 only features like that until the automated migration from Rhino to V8 is mostly complete." -- Google*

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for clarification folks!
Imho this thread can be closed now